# How do i plot a histogram from grouped data rather than raw

Tags: date-and-time, histograms

I have a data which is grouped in the following format:

```
{{date1,count1},{date2,count2},...}
```

I want to make a Date Histogram of this data. Apparently the acceptable format for mathematica is `{date1, date1,... (repeated count1 times), date2, date2,... (repeated count2 times), ...}`

I can convert it into the this format but there counts are in the millions and make the data uselessly huge after i extract it using group by using sql.

Is there a way to plot this histogram?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you're asking. It would be very helpful if could give a small dataset to work with and a concrete example of what the desired output is

Comment: I recommend the method in my answer there (even though it has the least votes). To use `DateHistogram` instead of `Histogram`, make sure that your dates are in AbsoluteTime format, i.e. instead of `{2017, 4, 19}` use `AbsoluteTime[{2017, 4, 19}]`

Comment: I don't quite understand, what's the difference between `data1` and `count1` exactly?

Comment: I thought this question was quite clear. Instead of `{4,4,4,5,5,6,7}` you have `{dataPoint, count}` pairs, i.e.`{{4,3}, {5,2}, {6,1}, {7,1}}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes that is what i want but the data is dates instead of numbers.

Comment: @user13892 "Dates" are numbers.  Pick a reference point in time, and use the time elapsed since them (in seconds, days, or whatever unit you please). Use the `AbsoluteTime` function to get this quickly, as I said in my comment above.